# Wsdl RPC to WSDL Document

Tags: wsdl

I have a requirement to integrate to a soap webservice, which provided wsdl RPC. However, the tools I'm using for integration doesnt support WSDL-RPC (OIC). Is there a way to invoke the soap webservice?

I already raised this and recommendation is to convert the wsdl-rpc into wsdl-document. I'm wandering if there are some other way.